# How i can compare the result in one query or two?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, smf

I am trying to fetch last 10 topics from smf database but topics are in two separate tables.

```
Subject, Post Time and Message ID in smf_messages.
Topic ID and Topic First Message in smf_topics.
```

I wrote this code to fetch topics but i dont know how to compare these two results.

```
$result = mysql_query("select subject,id_msg,id_topic from smf_messages");
$result2= mysql_query("select id_first_msg from smf_topics");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0)
{
    while($read = mysql_fetch_object($result))
    {
        if ($read->id_msg==$read->id_topic) {
            echo "<a href='../index.php?topic=" . $read->id_topic . "'>".$read->subject."</a><br>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: how you want to compare them?

Comment: What do you wanna do exactly? Do you want to search the first message from all topics?

Comment: I wanna compare id_first_msg from smf_topics with id_msg from smf_messages.

Comment: join in mysql query

Comment: id_first_msg and id_msg are the same id?

Comment: It's easier to do a join in mysql query and then fetch just the results you want from both tables, yes if your database definition is correct then they are. @RafaelShkembi

Comment: i will do the same thing but i want to be sure about the question that's why i asking ;) @FernandoZamperin

Comment: Thank you all for answers, i will try your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want the following query

```
select subject, id_msg, id_topic, id_first_msg
from smf_messages
left join smf_topics on smf_message.id_msg = smf_topics.id_first_msg
```

Answer (score 0):

bind the records by joining in sql:
`select subject id_msg, id_topic, id_first_msg from smf_messages
join smf_topics on smf_messages.id_msg = smf_topics.id_topic`

Answer (score 0):

mysql have many many options, with a small google search you could found about `left join`. 
[tuttorial and examples](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp).

Fist thing you have to do is stop using mysql_* and start using mysqli_* or pdo learn about [sql injections](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Your query should look like this.

```
select smf_messages.subject,smf_messages.id_msg,smf_messages.id_topic from smf_messages left join smf_topics on smf_topics.id_first_msg=smf_messages.id_msg
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that without using SQL, this is my solution it's not good but you can have an idea of how it works:

```
$messages = array();
$topics = array();

while($readmessage = mysql_fetch_object($resultmessage)) {
    array_push($messages, $readmessage);
}
while($readtopic = mysql_fetch_object($resulttopic)) {
    array_push($topics, $readtopic);
}

foreach ($topics as $topic) {
    $result = array_search($topic->id_first_message);
    if($result != true){
        //HERE $result IS THE INDEX OF FIRST MESSAGE IF IT IS IN THE MESSAGES ARRAY
        $messages[$result].id_msg //Access message attributes
    }
}
```